# Problem to install package RMySQL / Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, rmysql

R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) 
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit) 
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

When I try install the package RMySQL using the following command:

`install.packages('RMySQL')`

I got the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'RMySQL.so' failed

make: *** [RMySQL.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RMySQL’
* removing ‘/home/lepina/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/RMySQL’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RMySQL’ had non-zero exit status
```

I ask help because I don't know what else I might to do. I have already performed a R downgrade from 4.0.0 to 3.6.3 without success.

---

Following the recommendation from Dirk Eddelbuettel, and I run the following command line:
`sudo apt-get install r-cran-rmysql`
But I get another error message:

```
:~$ sudo apt-get install r-cran-rmysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-cran-rmysql : Depends: r-api-3.4
                 Depends: r-cran-dbi (>= 0.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I decided to fix the broken packages, using the couple of commands:

```
sudo apt update --fix-missing
sudo apt install -f
```

And forcing the manual installation of missing package  r-api-3.4, using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y r-api-3.4
```

But I got another error message that I don't have ideia about how to solve it:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Package r-api-3.4 is a virtual package provided by:
  r-base-core 3.4.4-1ubuntu1 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'r-api-3.4' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Please just try `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rmysql` --- there is a reason we provide binaries of "more complicated" packages.

Comment: The r-api-3.4 tag means that you have an older R installed -- with this binary API tag.  That is slight conflict with what you said earlier about R 4.0.0 or R 3.6.3.  _If_ you installed those from the package management system you'd have different tags (name `r-api-3.5` (not 3.6) and `r-api-4.0`.  Now there is hope: you could use the binaries off CRAN from the Rutter PPA, but it is a longer story.  We need to know more about exactly what you installed and from where.  Maybe come to the r-sig-debian list....

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server, on which I removed/purged the default R install completely. Next I have added the bionic-cran35 to the repositories

    deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/

after which I have installed R, 3.6.3. Next, using:

    sudo apt install r-cran-dbi

to install r-cran-dbi gives me:

    r-cran-dbi : Vereisten: r-api-3.4

I do not have an older R installed:

    apt list r-base-core
    Bezig met oplijsten... Klaar
    r-base-core/bionic-cran35,now 3.6.3-1bionic amd64 [geïnstalleerd]

Answer (score 0):

To make it visible for everybody else: Dirk's solution via terminal worked for me (Ubuntu 22.04): `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rmysql`